# Android Drawer items not working

Tags: java, android

I have created a drawer menu in android studio and changed items of drawer. I want to start another activity or view another layout on item click. but i get the following error and application is stopped.

```
03-24 21:38:28.202 2227-10289/? D/GassUtils: Found app info for package    com.example.imran.myapp:1. Hash: 6b9333e031907d7a6a6c12cd9fdfa0d23bd13ee0f40c9617ddd005dc358321b0
03-24 21:38:28.202 2227-10289/? D/k: Found info for package com.example.imran.myapp in db.
03-24 21:38:38.722 1035-1167/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.example.imran.myapp
03-24 21:38:38.782 9789-9789/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.imran.myapp time:121627337
03-24 21:38:38.802 1035-1853/? W/ActivityManager: NORMAL SET : srcAppInfo.processName = com.example.imran.myapp, destAppInfo.processName = com.example.imran.myapp
03-24 21:38:38.802 1035-1853/? W/ActivityManager: startActivity called from finishing ActivityRecord{28b176ac u0 com.example.imran.myapp/.MainActivity t2394 f}; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=com.example.imran.myapp/.Home (has extras) }
03-24 21:38:38.802 1035-1853/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.example.imran.myapp
03-24 21:38:39.402 1035-1532/? I/WindowManager: Switching to real app window: Window{11c67d3b u0 com.example.imran.myapp/com.example.imran.myapp.Home}
03-24 21:38:39.622 1035-1069/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{dca1b0 u0 com.example.imran.myapp/.Home t2396} time:121628177
03-24 21:38:58.462 9789-9789/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.imran.myapp, PID: 9789
                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(int)' on a null object reference
                                                 at com.example.imran.myapp.Home.onNavigationItemSelected(Home.java:120)
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:146)
                                                 at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
                                                 at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(SubMenuBuilder.java:84)
                                                 at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
                                                 at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
                                                 at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.onItemClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:196)
                                                 at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:334)
                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1536)
                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3683)
                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5604)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
03-24 21:38:58.462 1035-1514/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.example.imran.myapp
03-24 21:38:58.462 1035-1514/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.imran.myapp/.Home
03-24 21:38:58.462 1035-1514/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.example.imran.myapp
03-24 21:38:58.542 1035-1035/? D/CrashAnrDetector: processName: com.example.imran.myapp
03-24 21:38:58.542 1035-1035/? D/CrashAnrDetector: broadcastEvent : com.example.imran.myapp data_app_crash
03-24 21:38:58.992 1035-1062/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{dca1b0 u0 com.example.imran.myapp/.Home t2396 f}
```

Java files:
Home.java

```
package com.example.imran.myapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    Button logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout_button);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_sms);
    final UserLocalStore loginuser = new UserLocalStore(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("userDetails",0);
    String str1=(mPrefs.getString("fullname","Default_Value"));
    String email = loginuser.getLoggedInUser().email;
    text1.setText("Welcome "+str1+"- Your email: "+email);
    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginuser.clearUserData();
            //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));

            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    });





    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_photos) {
        // Handle the camera action
        //setContentView(R.layout.myaccount);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_myaccount) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myaccount2);
      //
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        UserLocalStore loginuser = new UserLocalStore(this);
        loginuser.clearUserData();

        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

In the last part of home.java when i add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_myaccount2);`
 then the app crashes.

Comment: Can you post the contents of activity_myaccount2.xml

Comment: sorry i have deleted that activity, but that activity was just a black, newly created activity. I Created new activity and tried to open that activity in the same way but no luck. I even tried to open another layout by `else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
              setContentView(R.layout.myaccount);
        }` but still app crashes. I deleted the whole home activity and created a fresh App Drawer activity, still same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is a Null Pointer Exception when calling `drawer.closeDrawer();` and as you've stated this happens after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_myaccount2);` is called.

By using setContentView, you're replacing your whole layout with another one, and it seems in this case like you're replacing your layout that contains R.id.drawer_layout with another one that doesn't contain it. The null pointer exception then happens when you try to use findViewById and closeDrawer, when the layout containing the drawer isn't there anymore, it's been replaced with another using setContentView.

To fix this you may need to rethink how you are structuring your app and displaying different content. As a starting point, I'd suggest looking up examples using an Activity which contains your drawer and Fragments to show the different pieces of content. The Activity and drawer are always there, only the fragments change, like [this tutorial](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/).